# Browser back does not work in reactjs application

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, state, history, back

New to reactjs and would like the browser back to go back to prior state.  But it just seems to go back to prior page.

package.json:

```
"react": "16.11.0",
"react-dom": "16.11.0",
"react-loader-spinner": "^3.1.5",
"react-promise-tracker": "^2.1.0",
"react-redux": "7.1.1",
"react-router": "5.1.2",
"react-router-dom": "5.1.2",
"react-scripts": "^3.2.0",
"reactstrap": "8.1.1",
"redux": "4.0.4",
"redux-thunk": "2.3.0",
```

index.tsx:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import jQuery from "jquery";
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { usePromiseTracker } from "react-promise-tracker";
import Loader from 'react-loader-spinner';

declare global {
    interface Window {
        $: any;
        jQuery: any;
    }
}
// export for others scripts to use
window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;

// Create browser history to use in the Redux store
const baseUrl = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].getAttribute('href') as string;
const history = createBrowserHistory({ basename: baseUrl });

// Get the application-wide store instance, prepopulating with state from the server where available.
const store = configureStore(history);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <App />
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'));

registerServiceWorker();
```

App.tsx:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import Layout from './components/Layout';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Counter from './components/Counter';
import Browser from './components/datagrid/Browser';

import '@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap/dist/all.css';
import './custom.css'

export default () => (
    <Layout>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Browser} />
    </Layout>
);
```

Just a single page at this point.  Desired state changes are effected via hyperlinks, and when using browser back button it moves out of the spa application since it browses to prior page.

```
<a title={props.dataItem.name} onClick={() => this.getItem('', props.dataItem.name)}>{props.dataItem.name}</a>
```

Relatively new to this and this is first reactjs web app.  Based on visual studio reacjs/asp.net core project template, with integrated redux.

Answer (score 1):

I was using hyperlink onClick to handle state transitions via reducers... this was the wrong place.

And it was just easier to relegate location change by pushing to history object on the onClick event...

But effect the reducer state change in listener for browser history change.  This way state changes were being handled in their correct place regardless of where the the browser location change was coming from- hyperlinks or browser buttons...

So changed to:

```
getItem(path: string, name: string) {
    path = path === '' ? this.pathurl : path; // this pathurl is internal variable for maintaining current path information, not germane to current discussion
    const { history } = this.props;
    if (history) history.push(path + name);
}


browserNavListener: any;

componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.location && this.props.location.pathname !== "/") {
        this.state.path = this.props.location.pathname;
        this.props.changePath(this.props.location.pathname);
    }

    this.browserNavListener = this.props.history.listen(location => {
        this.state.path = location.pathname;
        this.props.changePath(location.pathname);
    });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.browserNavListener();
}
```